# Как удалить линию в редакторе Webstorm

Tags: настройка, webstorm, редактор

Народ подскажите пожалуйста как можно удалить эту линию?
Ее вообще можно удалить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting → Editor → General → Appearance, снять галочку "Show right margin".